# How to show spreadsheet name in Logger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get a chart from spreadsheet `A`. I take this into a Chart object, and try to put it back in spreadsheet `B`.

I always get an 'unknown sheetname' error. I have been trying to put new ranges in the new chart, as you can see in the code. When I do a `Logger.log(newrange.getSheet())` I indeed get `Sheet` instead of `SHEETNAME`, like the chart builder messes with the sheetnames.

What is happening?

```js
function updateCharts() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEETNAME");
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();

  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("NEW ID");
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("SHEETNAME");

  for (var c=0; c<charts.length; c++) {

    var chart = charts[c];
    var ranges = chart.getRanges();
    var type = chart.getType();
    var info = chart.getOptions();

    var builder = chart.modify();

    var range = ranges[0];

    builder.removeRange(range);

    var startRow = range.getRow();
    var startCol = range.getColumn();
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var numCols = range.getNumColumns();

    var newrange = ss2.getSheetByName("statistiek").getRange(startRow, startCol,     numRows, numCols);

    Logger.log(newrange.getSheet());
    builder.addRange(newrange);

    var title = chart.getOptions().get('title')
    builder.setOption('title', title + " " + p);
    var newchart = builder.build();
    ss2.getSheetByName("statistiek").insertChart(newchart);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Logger.log()` requires a string, but you're feeding it an object with `newrange.getSheet()`. Try this instead, if you want the sheet's name:

```js
Logger.log(newrange.getSheet().getName())
```

To see the names of all sheets in a spreadsheet, try:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
for (i in allSheets) {
  Logger.log("Sheet " + i + " is named " + allSheets[i].getName());
}
```